# How do i get favorites icon set for icon datatype field using RestAPI for servicenow

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I need to show icon datatype custom field in my UI. For this, need to get favorites icon set from servicenow to show a icon list. Is there any RestAPI fo this?

Answer (score 0):

The icons of favorites are listed here: 
https://hi.service-now.com/styles/retina_icons/retina_icons.html

You can use them like this in the catalog: https://www.servicenowguru.com/scripting/client-scripts-scripting/button-colors-icons/

You can use them like this in the backend UI: https://servicenow.implementation.blog/great-ux-trick-field-decorations-and-there-295-hidden-icons/

Comment: Need Rest API url

Comment: There is no REST API URL for "favorites icon set"